# Symfony give class to option entitytype element

Tags: forms, symfony

i have an entity type with field (nome, id,id_Categoria,id_tipo) 
id_tipo has value 1,2,or 3

```
  $builder->add('idTipologiaEsame', EntityType::class, array(
        'placeholder' => 'tipologia esame',
                'label' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
        'required' => false,

        'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
                'choice_label' => 'nome',
                'group_by' => 'idCategoriaEsame.tipo',
            ))
```

My goal is give a class to option value in select if id_tipo is 1 or 2.

like this:

```
  <select>
    <option class="ruminanti">val 1</option>  ->id_tipo=1
    <option class="pippo">val 2</option>      ->id_tipo=2
    <option class="ruminanti">val 3</option>  ->id_tipo=1
    </select>
```

it is possible??

thank's to Ramazan Apaydın i add this

```
   $builder->add('idTipologiaEsame', EntityType::class, array(
            'placeholder' => 'tipologia esame',
                    'label' => false,
                    'mapped' => false,
            'required' => false,
                    'class' => 'AppBundle:Nome_esame',
                    'choice_label' => 'nome',
                    'group_by' => 'idCategoriaEsame.tipo',
             'choice_attr' => function($val, $key, $index) {
        // adds a class like attending_yes, attending_no, etc
            if($index){    ---->  i want id_tipo =1
            return ['class' => '.ruminati';}else{
                return ['class' => '.suini';

            }
    },
```

but i want add condition id_tipo=1

Comment: `if($index){    ---->  i want id_tipo =1` - then... do it? `if ($val->getIdTipo() == 1)` (or whatever your getter for that field is called).

Answer (score 3):

EntityType is a ChoiceType element. An example is available in the Symfony documentation.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-attr